# Will the uncaught Python exception lead to memory lead or other issues?

Tags: python, memory-leaks, exception, coding-style

There is an argument within my team for a code block of an internal using automation script.

The following function makes a network request and returns the result it has got.

The network request may fail due to IOError sometimes, but if the code retries, it will be able connect and get the result again. So the code have a retry mechanism to deal with such error.

But sometimes other errors happen, (like, say timeout or something). From the point of view of requirement, we should exit the script with an error code for such issues, so the calling program will know that something went wrong with the script and, say mail the engineers to let them to handle it.

Here is the code:

```
def my_func():
    retry_times = 5
    sleep_time = 5
    for i in range(0, 6)
        try:
            result = network_request()
            break
        except IOError as err:
            if i == retry_times:
                log.error
                raise
            else:
                log.warning("Request failed, sleep %s seconds and retry <%s/%s>"
                            % (sleep_time, i, retry_times))
    return result
```

But one of our team member argues that we should catch all the remaining exceptions, never let the exception to be thrown to the outer most code and finally make the script to exit with an error code and prints a stacktrace printing.

He calls this "exception leak", which violates common coding rule. Here goes his code (lines with "# Added code line" are the changed lines):

```
def my_func():
    retry_times = 5
    sleep_time = 5
    for i in range(0, 6)
        try:
            result = network_request()
            break
        except IOError as err:
            if i == retry_times:
                log.error
                raise
            else:
                log.warning("Request failed, sleep %s seconds and retry <%s/%s>"
                            % (sleep_time, i, retry_times))
        except Exception:  # Added code line
            log.error("Error happened: %s" % err)  # Added code line
            exit(1)
    return result
```

I said that he is doing things that Python has just done:

1. Print the error log.
2. Exist the script with non-zero exit code

But he argues that "how do you know that Python has done nothing when you catch the exception?", "leaving uncaught exception will cause memory leak", "any well designed program never leave uncaught exception to the end, it is a common sense".

This has confused me, cause I've never heard about such "common sense", especially for Python (no sure is C++ has this "common sense"). I Googled the topic and found that there is even nobody has asked such question. I've learned from the very beginning that the principle of exception handling is:

1. Handle those exceptions that your code is able to handle.
2. Raise those exceptions to the outer scope if you are unable to handle it.

In this case, since this script is an internal using automation script, when such an issue happens, printing a detail stacktrace and exit the script with non-zero error code is exactly what we want, cause the code cannot handle such issue so it should raise this finally to the engineers.

Adding a line which catches an unknown exception, print a error log and then exit the script with non-zero error code likes doing redundantly doing something that has already been done.

So here I'm asking:
 1. Will "leaving uncaught exception to the end and finally cause the script to exit" cause any issue like "memory leak" or something?
 2. Is there any such "common sense" in Python coding rule to no leave any uncaught exception to the end, providing "print error log" and "exit with non-zero code" is exactly what the script wants to do.

Comment: Uncaught exception will terminate the program, so who cares? And it is good programming style not to cough generic exception (like `Exception`). -- By exiting the program, kernel will free all resources (memory, files, network, etc.) -- BTW memory allocation should be minimal, so it is just internal memory allocation, and probably never asking kernel to allocate an other large memory buffer for subsequent memory allocation)

Comment: Not relevant, but shouldn't you `return result` inside the `try` block to avoid to repeat `network_request()`? Anyway, pretty sceptic about memory leaks due to uncaught exceptions. Uncaught exceptions just terminate the program, you have leaks when your program runs and you don't free unneeded resources.

Comment: @nicola The original program does have a "break" after network_request() but I missed to add it here (I've just added it now) so don't worry.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your other code. Many frameworks (such as Django) have a settings variable `DEBUG`. If that is set to true relevant data will be disclosed. If not users are displayed a 404 error.

If you are using a linter it tells you that catching unspecified exceptions is a bad practice